# MySQL query returns null values in PHP, but works normally

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code (simplified to highlight error):

```
SELECT @x := @x + 1 FROM some_table, (SELECT @x := 0) y
```

It works in mysql, but when I use it in PHP, it breaks and returns all NULL values. I know it has to do with the portion "@x + 1" because if I replace this portion with something else, for example 'test', it will work.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me (tested with PHP 5.6.30 and MySQL 8.0.0).

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT @x := @x + 1 FROM foo, (SELECT @x := 0) y");
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH));
```

Output (after I added three rows to my table `foo`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@x := @x + 1] => 1
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@x := @x + 1] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [@x := @x + 1] => 3
            [0] => 3
        )
)
```

Note that the associative array key is the full expression. You might want to give the column an alias in your query.

Comment: Hmm it does work. I guess I took away too much code to get to the minimal error case. I will keep playing around to see exactly where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `SET` like that.  Does it work with `SELECT`?

```
SELECT @x := @x + 1
FROM some_table CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @x := 0) y;
```

Comment: I mistyped, I meant to have "SELECT" in my code. Just changed it. Apologies for that